# Drupal 6: URL Alias setting for Vocabulary/Term to Term-customtext

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-path-aliases

I have a Vocabulary for location. and as a default it takes path as

> www.blabla.com/location/uk/london

and I need to make it as

> www.blabla.com/london-restaurant

My configurations are as below. but somehow it doesn't work at all :/ Appreciate advises!! Thanks a lot!

---

**Terms in Location view:**

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100702-ciramiub4ggxu3kpydbfh51xfk.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100702-ciramiub4ggxu3kpydbfh51xfk.jpg)

**Automated URL alias settings:**

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100702-deu42nqq4girx6jycyasypkg3i.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100702-deu42nqq4girx6jycyasypkg3i.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want `[cat-raw]-restaurant` for all location paths. You will need to clear and regenerate the paths aftewards.

Comment: i tried, but it doesn't change anything. I need to edit Taxonomy term path settings since I want to edit vocabulary/term links, am I wrong?

Comment: aha, my issue is different! http://drupal.org/node/125629 view url not able to override taxonomy url alias

Comment: I had to open and re-save all taxonomy terms, now it is fine.